# How to convert xls to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, silverstripe

How do you convert a large xls or csv dataset into mysql data using PHP and preferably using Silverstripe API? Can I do that directly or I need to convert first to text?

Comment: csv- php has built in functions: http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php etc, for xls there is [PHPexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) - mysql can import csv [directly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SilverStripe has a number of ways to import CSV files into your datamodel.

The documentation is worth reading on this section: 
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/integration/csv_import/

The quickest and simplest way is to manage your custom `DataObject` with a `ModelAdmin` interface and use the built in CSV importer.

```
class PlayerAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $managed_models = array(
        'Player'
    );
    private static $url_segment = 'players';
}
```

When you go to the Player `ModelAdmin` you will see a CSV import form on the left. Make sure the column titles in your CSV file line up with the variable names of your data object.

For more complex import methods read the documentation for alternative methods that allow you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
Example #1 Read and print the entire contents of a CSV file
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```